# How to change my sharepoint hostname?

Tags: sharepoint-foundation, sharepoint-server

For example my SharePoint site is open from `win-ah555085rrk/sites/empmgnt`, I want it to be accessible from `SPserver/sites/empmgnt`. How can this be done?

Answer (score 1):

go into iis manager.

click sites on left hand side. within the right hand side you should see a list of your sites. right click on the site you want to change the host headder for.

click on bindings... add name and set ip / port

next goto:

C:\Windows\System32\drivers\etc

open host file with text editor and add ip address and the name:

so witin bindings my host name is called 'intranet', its ip is set to all unasigned.

witin host file I have at the bottom:

126.0.10.1       intranet

the ip is the server ip and on the right is the name for the host you want to add that you setup within iis!

now do an iisreset and test.

step by step guide..... this is setting up iis and using central admin alernate acess mapping (aam)

http://blogs.technet.com/b/digital_musketeer/archive/2012/02/03/sharepoint-2010-configuring-urls-for-internet-use-aar-url-rewriting-alternate-access-mappings.aspx